# Real time with AngularJs & Yii2

Tags: angularjs, rest, websocket, yii2, real-time

I'm developing a Yii2 REST API, with AngularJS for the frontend to consume.

I need a way to implement real time approach, e.g. for a chat, or to make some real time notifications.

Is this possible, how to achieve? I been reading about Ratchet, Socket.io and some other things, but I couldn't figure out how to make them fit together for REST or if this is the way to go.

Any advice would be appreciate.

Comment: A REST API communicates over HTTP and real-time communication is most often done over WebSockets (with fallbacks to HTTP, but that's made transparent in good frameworks like Socket.io). The two are fundamentally different. That being said, there is no reason you can't have HTTP REST endpoints and a WebSockets endpoint in the same application.

Comment: So, is it possible to have the same REST API over a _**"websocket resource"**_? How to?

Comment: A REST API by convention uses HTTP request methods (`POST`/`PUT`/`DELETE`/`PATCH`) to specify the type of operation being requested (read/write/delete/update). This of course does not apply to WS. You can write a WS listener which accepts events containing a "type" or "method" property, and operates on entities. Note that this design violates REST architecture in multiple ways, and is more difficult to use from a client perspective.

Comment: A good design (in my opinion) is to have an application which listens on the HTTP(S) ports, and a designated route within the app to which WS connections can be made. This sort of thing is almost trivial to achieve using Express/Socket.IO (Node.js), but should also be possible using PHP+frameworks.

Comment: Thks @IgorRaush. You mean for example to have a URL inside the REST API wich will be the socket connection, something like `https://url.to.api/chat-messages`, all accessed by GET. Sorry if I didn't understand.

Comment: Yes, that's right, although your terminology is not really correct. You will have a web application which encapsulates **both** an HTTP REST API, and a real-time WebSockets endpoint. [Here](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4) is how it is accomplished using Express/Socket.IO. This is just a demonstration of the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here.

Short / Long Polling (use setTimeout)

```
app.controller("MyController", function($scope, $timeout, $http) {
    $scope.messages = [];

    $timeout(callAtTimeout, 3000);

    function callAtTimeout() {
        console.log("Timeout occurred");
        $http.get('PATH TO RESOURCE TO GET NEW MESSAGES').then(
            function(res) { // update $scope.messages etc... },
            function(err) { // handle error }
        );
    }
});
```

For both short and long polling on client side, you send request, wait to get a response back, then wait 3 seconds and fire again.

Short/Long polling works differently on the server side. Short polling will just return a response immediately - whether something has changed or not. Long polling, you hold the connection open and when there is a change, then you return the data. Beware of keeping too many connections open.

Socket.io (websockets)

I would recommend that you implement websockets using either something like node.js on your own web server or a hosted solution like Firebase.

The thing with Firebase is that from PHP, you can send a post request to a REST endpoint on the firebase server. Your javascript can connect to that endpoint and listen for changes and update the dom accordingly. It is possibly the simplest of all to implement.

I personally wouldnt use PHP for socket programming but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

To have real-time updates on your website, you can implement one of the following approaches depending on your requirement and how fast you need to update your frontend component.

**Using a websocket**

You can use a library like https://github.com/consik/yii2-websocket to implement it with Yii2. But this will act as a separate service from your REST API. Therefore you have to make sure that proper security practices are applied.

**Running an Angular function with a timeout**

You can continuously poll an endpoint of the REST API with a timeout of few milliseconds to receive updated values.

***The second approach will create many requests to the API which will increase the server load. Therefore my preferred approach is using a websocket.***